# NullPointerException while creating AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have simple method with `AsyncTask`, but code suddenly crashed. Any ideas?
I got `Could not parse malformed JSON:`, and now I get NPE at `new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {`
My code:

```
private void getMyPage() {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfileActivity.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Create Dialog...
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

                data.put("token", params[0]);

                LoginLectorUtils apiUtils = new LoginLectorUtils();
                return apiUtils.sendPostRequestWithParams(REQUEST_URL, data);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                super.onPostExecute(response);
                dialog.dismiss();

                if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                    try {
                        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        if (jsonObject.getString("error").equals("true")) {
                            showDialogConnectionError();
                        } else if (jsonObject.getString("error").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                            doLoadStuff(
                                    jsonObject.getString("name"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("phone")
                        }

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("UserProfileActivity", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + response + "\"");
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        }.execute(sharedPrefUtils.getToken());
    }
```

Comment: @bigdestroyer, but I got NPE now

Comment: In which line? Maybe `dialog` is null. Can u show the `onPreExecute` code?

Comment: @bigdestroyer, the problem was in SharedPreferences...